# Python Remove backslashes before a set of characters

Tags: python, string, backslash

How could I remove the backslash before a character in Python, such as ":" or "!"?

Edit: Let's say I got this line : `"This is a line of text\!"` . I want to get just `"This is a line of text!"`, without the backslash.

Comment: could you be more specific? plese, explain what you have and what you want to get?

Comment: What about the backslashes that escape special characters? like in `'It\'s 12 o\'clock'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex here:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "This is a line of text\!, hello\: It\"s"
>>> re.sub(r'\\([!:])', r'\1', s)
'This is a line of text!, hello: It"s'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all backslashes, a simpler way is:

```
print "This is a line of text\!".replace('\\','')
```

Note that you have to escape the backslash, and that you may remove backslashes that are used to escape other characters.